# WP/ACF Query post from selection

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

This is probably way my pay-grade but I gotta start somewheres. I'm building a Wordpress site with the assistance of ACF. One section of the site contains employee profiles with standard contact information.

Another section of the site lists projects. As part of the admin interface I've included a dropdown select so the admin can assign employees to projects and relevant contact info is associated with that project. This way the admin won't have to manually enter email address, phone, etc.

I assume by identifying the employee in the select I should be able to extract the post_ID then run a query to get the data and that's about as far as I can see this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is assuming that you're using the Post Object field to select the employee. Also make sure you're returning the 'post object' from within the field's settings, rather than just the post ID.

At that point, in your code, you can pull the value from the custom field, setup the post object for that employee, and then just use standard Wordpress or ACF functions to pull data from that employee, like `the_content()` or `get_field()`

```
<?php
$employee = get_field('employee');
if( $employee ) {
    $post = $employee;
    setup_postdata( $post ); 

    // At this point you can pull any data from the employee post that you need.

    wp_reset_postdata(); // Make sure to reset postdata when you're done.
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you JohnnyD, this put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, this small addition to the correct answer was a complete solution:

```
<?php
  $employee = get_field('employee');
  if( $employee ): 
  // override $post
  global $post;
  $post = $employee;
  setup_postdata( $post ); 
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```